# making arrays with awk when number of columns vary

Tags: arrays, awk

I have comma-delimited, data such as:

```
WP, 2012120100, 30, 989, 50, 1050, 50, 50, 1007
WP, 2012120106, 35, 987, 45, 1045, 50, 50, 1006
WP, 2012120112, 40, 985, 
WP, 2012120118, 50, 980, 55, 1065, 65, 60, 1008
```

I want to turn each column into an array, such as:

```
set -A col2 `awk -F, {print $2} myfile`
```

--> this works fine, yeilding array values of

```
2012120100, 2012120106, 2012120112, 2012120118
```

However if I do:

```
set -A col5 `awk -F, {print $5} myfile`
```

the array "col5" has values 50, 45, 55.  I need to keep a blank or null value for any missing columns, such that the array "col5" would be 50, 45,  ,55, otherwise my arrays no longer line up.

Answer (score 2):

What language is that you're calling awk from? Here's bash in UNIX:

```
$ col5="$(awk -F, '{print $5}' myfile)"
$ echo "${col5[@]}"
 50
 45

 55
```

Comment: I was using ksh.  That solution still has the same problem I am trying to solve.  I want the resulting array to be 50, 45,  , 55 -- not 50,45,55. Some lines of my data, such as line 3 in my example, are missing data - so I need the array to be a null value for missing indices (I hope that is the correct terminology).

Comment: Please re-read the output I posted. It IS 50, 45,  , 55 as you requested. If there's something else you need let us know what it is.